# Laravel Relation Query/Find - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, find, relation

I'm not able to fix this error when I tried associate category to transaction.

// TransactionController

```
$transactions = DB::table('transactions')
        ->where('status', 'false')
        ->orderBy('date','asc')
        ->get();        

        foreach($transactions as $data) {
            $transaction = new Transaction();
            $transaction->id = $data->id;
            $transaction->category = Transaction::find($data->categories_id)->category;
            $transaction->description = $data->description;
    }
```

The error occurs at time:
ErrorException in TransactionController.php line 80:
Trying to get property of non-object

```
Line 80: $transaction->category = Transaction::find($data->categories_id)->category;
```

But, if I test my code with die, that's result:

```
die(Transaction::find($data->categories_id)->category()->first());

{"id":1,"users_id":1,"description":"Alimenta\u00e7\u00e3o","created_at":"2016-11-15 20:31:11","updated_at":"2016-11-15 20:31:11"}
```

// Transaction Model

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    public function category(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Category','id');
    }
```

[]'s

Comment: can you `dd` the content of `$transactions`

Comment: `Transaction::find($data->categories_id)->category` Why are you trying to find a `Transaction` by using a `categories_id`? :/

Comment: check all the `$data->categories_id`, some may not have the transaction id.

Comment: @Doom5 thanks man, I was searching wrong.

Comment: @Sanzeeb Aryal, some transactions were from other users, then it was not possible to find the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error as one or multiple `$data->categories_id` are not matching the `id` on the `transactions` table.

**Note:**
It's not a good practice to `find` a model and call a function on it on the same line as you have done.

`Transaction::find($data->categories_id)->category;`

Because, you never know what `id` will be passed as argument to `find()`.
Better go for `findOrFail()`.

```
$tran = Transaction::findOrFail($data->categories_id);

$cat = $tran->category;
```

The `findOrFail()` function will throw a `ModelNotFoundException` whenever the `id` doesn't match in the `transactions` table. This exception can be easily handled by `try...catch` block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll use findOrFail, it makes perfect sense. Also, I changed the search because I needed to retrieve the information from the associated category. `$cat = Category::findOrFail($data->categories_id);`.